# iOS Cordova PushBots Registers a device but no alerts are pushed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, pushbots

I think I have everything up and running, I've registered with PushBots, I've created my App.. I've Created my p12 and uploaded it to the app, I've created my provisioning certificate and added it to xcode. I've added the initialisation code to my app and when I run it, my device (iPhone 7) gets added as a device.... But When I push a notification, it says it has gone, but nothing happens on the phone?

I can programatically add a badge to my icon...

Is there something missing, when the app first loaded it said that it wanted to accept notifications which of course I agreed to.... Just won't accept a notification.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I load my app, I get the "this app would like to send notification" prompt and my app appears in the iphone notification settings... So something is happening somewhere, just that my app and appbots is not tallying up somewhere it seems?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: I am also having the same issue.